# How to remove all roles from a member with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

so  i want to make a command that removed all the roles from a member and adds a role to the member after clearing the roles from him/her
here is what i have

```
@client.command()
async def prison(ctx, member: discord.Member):
   role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Prisoner')
   await member.remove_roles(member.roles)
   await member.add_roles(role)
   await ctx.send(f"{member} is imprisoned!")
```

now this adds the role to them but doesnt clear roles, anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove **all** the roles it is easier to use the `edit()` method. Like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def prison(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Prisoner")
    await member.edit(roles=[])
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} is imprisoned!")
```

*Also if you get the `MissingPermissions` error it means that the Bot is lower in hierarchy then the user that you want to "imprison". To fix that, in guild settings move bots role higher then this user role.

If you have any more problems feel free to ask in comments.